# add specfic statistical columns that summarize cloumns according to ID and vists in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

please i need to make update in data frame
the current dataframe like this

```
ID      visit         feature 1      feature 2
1       m1              2               4
1       m2              5               9
1       m3              3               4
1       m4              4               0
2       m1
2       m2              5               6
2       m2              4               4
2       m4              3               3
```

i want it  aggregate the features of all subjects in all visits and make one row for each subject that include avg, max ,min of all features to be like the following

```
ID      Max_feature1    min_feature1      max_feature2      min_feature2      
1          5                2                 9                  0
2         5                 3                 6                  3
```

so for every ID to have aggregated the visits for all id and save only the statistics feature of each feature then save it again to a CSV file

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You're looking for a `groupby`. Here is some more info from the pandas User Guide: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html Hint: `df.groupby("ID").agg(["mean", "max", "min"])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and then optionally flatten the multiindex:

```py
df = df.groupby('ID')[['feature 1', 'feature 2']].agg(['min', 'max'])
df.columns = ["_".join(a) for a in df.columns.to_flat_index()]
```

Output:

```
    feature 1_min  feature 1_max  feature 2_min  feature 2_max
ID                                                            
1             2.0            5.0            0.0            9.0
2             3.0            5.0            3.0            6.0
```